# how to use C++ macro in SWIG interface

Tags: python, c++, swig

```
%{
#define FOOBAR foobar
%}


%define MACRO(cl)

%pythoncode %{
    def cl():
            return
%}

%enddef

MACRO(FOOBAR)
```

I would like that the resulting SWIG Python code had `foobar()` defined.  But the C macro does not take effect - I only have `FOOBAR()`.

How to enable SWIG interface to use C macros?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've got is very close. Specifically you have:

> ```
> %{
> #define FOOBAR foobar
> %}
> ```

However `%{ %}` just makes SWIG pass what's contained out to the generated .cxx file - it doesn't parse or considered what's there. In effect SWIG ignores that `#define` and lets the compiler later take care of it.

So you can simply fix it with:

```
#define FOOBAR foobar

%define MACRO(cl)

%pythoncode %{
    def cl():
            return
%}

%enddef

MACRO(FOOBAR)
```

Which works as you'd hoped because the SWIG preprocessor now gets to see the macro.

(Note: if you've used `#include` inside `%{ %}` you'll want to use `%include` instead for similar reason again. `%include` causes SWIG itself to read and interpret the contents of the file)

Comment: Duh!  The manual says so.  I just failed to properly appreciate what it says.